# tensorflow while loop slows down

Tags: python, tensorflow

The problem is a tensorflow while loop (*tf.while_loop*) that slows down over time. The loop is supposed to return some matrices. I feed all inputs through a dictionary.

I am aware that the problem is most likely caused by polluting the graph by adding operations over and over again. I am a TF beginner and for me, it is not obvious what causes polluting the graph here. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
def predict(self, actions, ...):


    feed_dict = {
        self.agent.actions: actions.reshape(-1, self.kwargs["dim_actions"]),
        ...
    }

    states_mu, states_var = self.session.run(self.agent.predict_states(), feed_dict=feed_dict)

    return states_mu, states_var


def predict_states(self):
   ...

    def loop_cond(i, state_mus, state_vars, state_mus_tf, state_vars_tf, inp_tf_cov):
        return i < self.episode_length

    def loop_body(i, state_mus, state_vars, state_mus_tf, state_vars_tf, inp_tf_cov):
        state_mu_i = state_mus[-1][None, :]
        ...
        state_var_tf = state_vars_tf[-1][None, :, :]

        #Some math operations
        ...

        new_state_mu = state_mu_i + delta_mu
        new_state_var = state_var_i + delta_var + inp_out_cov

        new_mu_tf, new_var_tf, inp_tf_cov = some_transform(
            new_state_mu, ....)

        state_mus = tf.concat([state_mus, new_state_mu], 0)
        ...
        state_vars_tf = tf.concat([state_vars_tf, new_var_tf], 0)

        i += 1

        return i, state_mus, state_vars, state_mus_tf, state_vars_tf, inp_tf_cov

    loop_step = tf.constant(0, tf.int32)
    init_mus_tf, init_vars_tf, inp_tf_cov = some_transform(
        self.state_mu, self.state_var, self.dim_angles)

    loop_vars = [
        loop_step,
        self.state_mu,
        self.state_var,
        init_mus_tf,
        init_vars_tf,
        inp_tf_cov]

    shapes = [loop_step.get_shape(),
              tf.TensorShape([None, self.dim_states]),
              tf.TensorShape([None, self.dim_states, self.dim_states]),
              tf.TensorShape([None, self.dim_states_tf]),
              tf.TensorShape([None, self.dim_states_tf, self.dim_states_tf]),
              inp_tf_cov.get_shape()]

    _, state_mus, state_vars, state_mus_tf, state_vars_tf, inp_tf_cov = tf.while_loop(
        loop_cond,
        loop_body,
        loop_vars=loop_vars,
        shape_invariants=shapes)

    return state_mus_tf[1:], state_vars_tf[1:]
```

The loop is called multiple times. It slows down within a run, i.e. after each iteration and even further after repeated calls. The iteration speed of each run starts where the last run ended. 
For example, at the beginning of the first run, it takes  1 second per iteration, at the end of the first run, it takes 3 seconds per iteration. At the beginning of the second run, it takes 3 seconds per iteration, ... until it gets infeasible to let it run (e.g. 100 seconds per iteration).

Answer (score 0):

The code seems mostly fine, but you should call `predict_states` only once, when you create the instance of your class (or on some other initialization step), and store the return values in class attributes. For example:

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    # ...
    self.states_mu_tf, self.states_var_tf = self.agent.predict_states()
```

Then, you use those attributes in `predict`:

```
states_mu, states_var = self.session.run((self.states_mu_tf, self.states_var_tf),
                                         feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

That way you will not be recreating operations in the graph.